# get utf8 urlencoded characters in another page using php

Tags: php, utf-8

I have used rawurlencode on a utf8 word. 
For example

```
$tit = 'தேனின் "வாசம்"';
$t = (rawurlencode($tit));
```

when I click the utf8 word ($t), I will be transferred to another page using .htaccess and I get the utf8 word using $_GET['word'];

The word displays as à®¤à¯‡à®©à®¿à®©à¯_"à®µà®¾à®šà®®à¯" not the actual word. How can I get the actual utf8 word. I have used the header charset=utf-8.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Was my comment first, but should have been an answer:

`magic_quotes` is off? Would be weird if it was still on in 2011. But you should check and do `stripslashes`.

Answer (score 0):

Did you use `rawurldecode($_GET['word']);` ? And do you use UTF-8 encoding for your PHP file?

Comment: Ya I have used rawurldecode. If the word doesn't contain quotes it is displayed properly. I have issues only if the word contains quotes. I haved used <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" /> in header

Comment: `magic_quotes` is off? Would be weird if it was still on in 2011. But you should check and do stripslashes _first_.

Comment: @nithi not the header i was asking about but the encoding the script file was saved with (nice sentence hehe =) ). I created a simple two-files test (the first file sets rawurlencoded-GET-value and redirects to the second one) - it worked great as i saved both files as UTF-8.

Comment: @ontrack errr... what sense makes `magic_quotes` option or `stripslashes` function applied to this question???

Comment: @shybovycha Because nithi says in the comment above mine: "If the word doesn't contain quotes it is displayed properly. I have issues only if the word contains quotes."

Comment: @ontrack sorry, messed up with `short_tag` =P

Comment: @shybovycha and ontrack: I have used stripslashes and it works. Thank u

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$s1 = <<<EOD
à®¤à¯‡à®©à®¿à®©à¯_"à®µà®¾à®šà®®à¯"
EOD;
$s2 = <<<EOD
தேனின் "வாசம்"
EOD;

$s1 = mb_convert_encoding($s1, "WINDOWS-1252", "UTF-8");

echo bin2hex($s1), "\n";
echo bin2hex($s2), "\n";
echo $s1, "\n", $s2, "\n";
```

Output:

```
e0aea4e0af87e0aea9e0aebfe0aea9e0af5f22e0aeb5e0aebee0ae9ae0aeaee0af22
e0aea4e0af87e0aea9e0aebfe0aea9e0af8d2022e0aeb5e0aebee0ae9ae0aeaee0af8d22
தேனின��_"வாசம��"
தேனின் "வாசம்"
```

You're probably just not showing the data as UTF-8 and you're showing it as ISO-8859-1 or similar.