# php urlencod utf-8 string makes it ascii in mb_detect_encoding

Tags: php, utf-8, get, http-headers, ascii

During my work in updating some old projects im working through some old ANSI/ASCII files and encodings.
I want to have everything running utf-8 to make sure that i can support all kinds of languages.

I have a service where i send out sms'es using a microservice. I have an endpoint: /sms.php where i accept some parameters from _GET and these are then used in the application.
I have some test files where i make some requests to test if everything is ok.
My problem is that even though all files are utf8-encoded (i've checked multiple times)

My code looks like this:

```
$text = "message with æøå to make it utf8";
$params = urlencode($text);
$url = "http://localhost/sms.php?text=".$params;
echo mb_detect_encoding($text, "auto"); // this prints utf8
echo mb_detect_encoding($url, "auto"); // this prints ascii
$res = file_get_contents($url);
```

And this is also what i see in my receiving endpoint.

First i thought it was something to do with file_get_contents but since its being converted AFTER the urlencode it thought i might be it. But im not sure how to get around this problem.
The other problem i have is that a lot of my clients are using this old 2012 code (before i started using utf8 as standard) so i cant change the endpoint without causing them to make changes in their current setups.

In a comment i've been suggested to try to check for if the string is utf8 using
bin2hex:

```
bin2hex($_GET['text']); // 6d657373616765207769746820c3a6c3b8c3a520746f206d616b652069742075746638 which is inserted into the database: message with Ã¦Ã¸Ã¥ to make it utf8
bin2hex(utf8_decode($_GET['text'])); // 6d657373616765207769746820e6f8e520746f206d616b652069742075746638 which is inserted into the database: message with æøå to make it utf8
```

Hope someone out there can point me in a correct direction.
I've looked into multiple stackoverflow entries for example
[get utf8 urlencoded characters in another page using php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7738031/get-utf8-urlencoded-characters-in-another-page-using-php)
[What's the correct encoding of HTTP get request strings?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1549213/whats-the-correct-encoding-of-http-get-request-strings)

but im not sure if what im looking for is even possible?
i was just hoping to be able to rewrite entire project to be utf8-ready

Thanks
/Wel

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`mb_detect_encoding` gives you the first encoding in which the tested string is valid. If left to its own devices, it tests for ASCII before UTF-8. Since a URL-encoded string consists solely of a subset of ASCII characters, it is valid ASCII and `mb_detect_encoding` will tell you so. Whereas a string containing non-ASCII characters is not valid ASCII, so it will continue testing other encodings and eventually arrive at UTF-8.

UTF-8 is a superset of ASCII, so any string that is valid ASCII is also valid UTF-8. A string can be valid in multiple encodings at once; `mb_detect_encoding` telling you it's valid ASCII does ***not*** mean that it's *not* also valid UTF-8, or Latin-1, or numerous other encodings for that matter. That's how [Mojibake](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mojibake) is born.

*Detecting* encodings is largely vague nonsense anyway and you should never do that. If you expect a string to be in UTF-8, simply test whether it is valid UTF-8 or not:

```
mb_check_encoding($url, 'UTF-8')
```

If it's not valid in the expected encoding, discard it, since you have no clue what it really is then.

Comment: Hi Thanks for reply. I'm sorry i didnt mention that i am well aware of that detection can be ordered so that it starts with utf8 instead of ascii, but doing this doesnt explain why on the receiving end i need to make utf8_decode to be able to read it as utf8 and get it inserted into the db correct.
        $_GET['text'] = utf8_decode($_GET['text']);

Comment: That is a completely different cattle of worms. Likely `$_GET['text']` is perfectly fine UTF-8, and you're simply not treating the encoding settings correctly when inserting into the database. Use `echo bin2hex($_GET['text'])` to see the *bytes* your string consists of and check whether they represent the correct encoding for the characters you expect.

Comment: i tried that and yes, the string does look like still to contain utf8 - but then inserting it into the db makes it all go away again? i understand this is outside the scope of this question, but perhaps i can change it a little to fit

Comment: Likely you need to follow https://stackoverflow.com/a/279279/476 closely.

Comment: That was exactly it. Using set_charset i was able to make it work in the database aswell.. Thanks!